# How to bind event in MarkupString

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, webassembly, event-binding

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_markup))
{
    @((MarkupString)_markup)
}
```

```
@code {
    public string _markup = "<ul><li class='li-a'>A</li><li class='li-a'>B</li></ul>";
}
```

I want bind event in MarkupString.

I'm leaving a question because I don't have enough knowledge about Blazor, and because of that, I don't have enough keywords to search on Google.

ex)

```
public string _markup = "<ul><li class='li-a' @onclick="(e) => clicktext(e)">A</li><li class='li-a' @onclick="(e) => clicktext(e)">B</li></ul>";


    void clicktext(object e)
    {
        //code here..
    }
```

Comment: What are your limitations? Why are you using a string instead of components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with MarkupString.  If you want interactive behaviour you need to use a `RenderFragment`.  As you haven't provided any context to your question, I don't know if this remotely fits your use case.

Here's a quick example:

```cs
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@_markup

@code{
    private RenderFragment _markup => (__builder) =>
    {
    <ul>
        <li class="li-a" @onclick="OnClickText">A</li>
        <li class="li-a" @onclick="OnClickText">B</li>
    </ul>
    };

    private Task OnClickText(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //code here..
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```